# Como evitar a confusão de querys executadas ao mesmo tempo com Php e Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

tenho essa função php (setBet) que cadastra as apostas no meu sistema baseado na BetFair, o fato é que estou querendo expandir o negócio e provavelmente algum apostador vai fazer uma aposta ao mesmo tempo que outro. A função abaixo Cadastra primeiro o cabeçalho da aposta na tabela "bet" e com a função sleep(1) eu espero 1 segundo para a inserção da query logo após, com a função SELECT MAX(id) eu seleciono o id que acabei de cadastrar para usar na foreignkey da tabela "bet_matches" que cadastra qual partida o cliente apostou, e o id da aposta dele.

**MEU PROBLEMA : por usar a função sleep(1) e a MAX(id) eu com certeza vou ter algum problema no futuro, de mistura de apostas ou coisa parecida.. então, como posso fazer para melhorar essa função ?**

```
public function setBet($punter_name, $punter_phone, $value, $colab_id, $array_match_and_bet)
{
    // Cadastrar Cabeçalho e Pegar ID Aposta
    $query =    "SET TIME_ZONE = '-03:00';";
    $query .= "INSERT INTO bet(id, punter_name, punter_phone, value, colab_id, date_time, possible_prize) values(NULL, '$punter_name', '$punter_phone', '$value', '$colab_id', now(), 0);";
    $data = mysqli_multi_query(Conexao::conectar(), $query) or die(Conexao::conectar());

    // Se Dados For Verdadeiro, Cabeçalho cadastrado
    if ($data){
        // Espera um segundo e Pega o id que acabamos de gerar
        sleep(1);
        $query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM bet";
        $data = mysqli_query(Conexao::conectar(), $query);
        $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
        $last_id = $line["MAX(id)"];
        // Hora de cadastrar as partidas selecionadas Bitch
        sort($array_match_and_bet);
        $count = count($array_match_and_bet);
        for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
            $match_and_bet = explode('-', $array_match_and_bet[$i]);
            // var_dump($match_and_bet);
            $id_match = $match_and_bet[0];
            $type_bet = $match_and_bet[1];
            $odd_at_time = $match_and_bet[2];
            // Vetor para ser utilizado no calculo do premio possivel
            $odds[] = $match_and_bet[2];
            $query = "INSERT INTO `bet_matches` SET match_id = $id_match, type_bet = '$type_bet', bet_id = $last_id, datetime_add = now(), odd_at_time = $odd_at_time";
            // var_dump($query);
            $data = mysqli_query(Conexao::conectar(), $query);
            if (!$data) {
                exit();
            }
        }
        // Calcula a cotacao
        $possible_prize = Bet::calcBetPossiblePrize($odds) * $value;
        // Guarda o Premio Possivel
        Bet::setPossiblePrize($possible_prize, $last_id);

        if ($data) {
                header("Location: ../bet_details.php?bet_id=".$last_id."&msg=betMakeSuccess");
            }
            else{
                header("Location: ../bet_details.php?bet_id=".$last_id."&msg=betMakeDuplicate");
            }

    }
    else
        return 0;   
}
```

EDITADO: SEGUE MINHA FUNÇÃO Conexao::conectar()

```
public static function conectar()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vagrant', 'boleiros') or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        //you need to exit the script, if there is an error
        exit();
    }
    return $con;
    // var_dump($con);
}
```

Comment: Porque o uso do sleep?

Comment: por que as vezes rola um delay no registro da query, e se a query não tiver sido executada ainda quando chegar a execução do MAX(id) ele pega o id da aposta anterior, aí embola tudo .. pq ele cadastra a nova aposta junto à aposta anterior :/

Comment: Delay da query? Õ.o

Comment: um atraso Fleuquer, no registro da query .. Se o tempo de processamento da query for de 0,4s e o tempo de execução do script for de 0,2s ? Obviamente o script não vai pegar o novo id e sim o id da aposta anterior --'

Comment: Vai sim, porque o próprio script php não vai avançar sem o passo anterior estar concluido. Perdia-se toda a lógica de um programa se assim fosse. Imagine que declara que `x=1` e depois faz `y=x+2`, obviamente para que o y seja criado precisa de haver um x...

Comment: Eu sei o que é um delay, eu perguntei porque não era para o tempo influenciar já que uma só deveria ser executada após a outra ser terminada. Se isso não acontece deveria rever sua estrutura para sua própria segurança.

Comment: O @Miguel está certo, não faz sentido o próximo passo ser executado sem que o anterior tenha sido concluído.

Comment: Vou testar primeiro deste jeito ai que vcs estao falando e volto pra dar o retorno

Comment: @YuriFoxx por essa lógica o que lhe garantiria que 1 segundo bastava?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É muito importante que guarde a conecção numa variável para não estar sempre a conectar-se. Eu não sei como tem a sua conecção mas tente assim:

```
....
$conn = Conexao::conectar(); 
$query = "SET TIME_ZONE = '-03:00';";
$conn->query($query) or die('Erro na definição da timezone, tente mais tarde');
$query = "INSERT INTO bet (id, punter_name, punter_phone, value, colab_id, date_time, possible_prize) values(NULL, '$punter_name', '$punter_phone', '$value', '$colab_id', now(), 0);";
$data = $conn->query($query) or die('Erro na inserção, tente mais tarde');
$lastId = $conn->insert_id; // aqui guarda este e só este id, desta conecção que inseriu o novo dado

$query = "SELECT * FROM bet WHERE id=" .$lastId;
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    ....
```

Comment: Vou testar e respondo vc aqui ! Mas de antemão, já gostei da sua resposta !

Comment: Obrigado  @YuriFoxx, tenta só a certeza que `Conexao::conectar()` retorna uma conecção, senão peço-lhe que coloque o método conectar() na pergunta também para o ajudarmos consoante isso

Comment: Editei um pequeno detalhe em cima @YuriFoxx, na declaração de `$lastId`

Comment: Com esse script não tem necessidade do sleep não

Comment: Nem precisa do `if($data) {`, porque $data ou existe ou é die()

Comment: eu poderia passar a conexão por um parâmetro $con nesse caso ? e sempre quando eu chamar a $con ele fará referencia à mesma conexão ou abrirá outra ?

Comment: Sim, se guardar a conexão numa variável, tudo o que fizer na base de dados com aquela conexão só vai pertencer áquela conecção

Comment: Editei o `die('Erro na inserção, tente mais tarde')` em cima, não sei se chegou a ver... Mas assim vai ter o que queria, o ultimo id inserido por aquela conecção... Ecusa de ter o sleep assim. E depois dentro do `if` pode alterar `$data = mysqli_query(Conexao::conectar(), $query);` para `$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);`

Comment: Cheguei a ver estou implementando agora .. vamos ver se roda liso

Comment: o $con->insert_id; está retornando (0)  ! por que sera ?

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e colocar lá o seu metodo `conectar()` sff

Comment: Está a inserir?

Comment: pronto, ta editado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41505/discussion-between-miguel-and-yuri-foxx).